# Oracle: Sql to update row of the same table based on value from another row of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a sql to update the price column to 999 for the item records which meet the following condition:

1. The location of the ITEM should not be null for both the records.
2. Update the price to 999 for which one of the 2 records has location as null.

```
 
ID   LOCATION   ITEM   PRICE
1    NULL       101    0
2    123        101    0
3    NULL       102    0
4    NULL       102    0
5    124        103    0
6    NULL       103    0
```

### OUTPUT TABLE SAMPLE

```
 
ID   LOCATION   ITEM   PRICE
1    NULL       101    999
2    123        101    0
3    NULL       102    0
4    NULL       102    0
5    124        103    0
6    NULL       103    999
```

Comment: I've posted an answer. (Had to update it, because I confused location and price two times.) It is not clear by the way, what your actual problem was. The statement is rather straight-forward, as you can see. Next time show your update statement and tell us where you get stuck with it.

Comment: Please post the query/approach you have tried. Don't post such things as I need a query for this.

Comment: I used the below query but its updating only one set where the first id record is null:

UPDATE SAMPLE SAMP2 SET SAMP2.PRICE=999 WHERE SAMP2.ID IN (SELECT SAMP2.ID FROM SAMPLE SAMP1 JOIN SAMPLE SAMP2 ON SAMP1.ITEM=SAMP2.ITEM WHERE SAMP1.SLOT_ID IS NOT NULL AND SAMP2.SLOT_ID IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` (or `EXISTS`) to check for the existence of a record with the item number where location is not null.

```
update items
set price = 999
where location is null
and item_id in (select item_id from items where location is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a table. Please find the query below. Just execute and check. You should get the desired result as per your ask.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(ID INT, LOCATION INT, ITEM INT, PRICE INT)
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
(1, NULL, 101, 0), 
(2, 123 , 101, 0), 
(3, NULL, 102, 0), 
(4, NULL, 102, 0), 
(5, 124 , 103, 0), 
(6, NULL, 103, 0);

SELECT* FROM TABLE1;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ITEM, COUNT(*) AS COUNTLOC FROM TABLE1 WHERE LOCATION IS NULL GROUP BY ITEM
)
UPDATE TABLE1
SET PRICE = 999 WHERE ITEM IN(SELECT ITEM FROM CTE WHERE COUNTLOC<2) AND LOCATION IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN (select t12.item from TABLE1 t12 where t12.LOCATION is null
GROUP BY t12.ITEM 
HAVING count(t12.ITEM)=1)aaa on aaa.item = t1.ITEM
set t1.PRICE = 999 where t1.LOCATION is null
```